# Call Javascript function only when checkbox is NOT checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out how to call a Javascript function only when a checkbox is NOT checked.

Here is my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="icd" name="icd" value="icd" />
```

Here is the name of the function:

```
planhide();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('icd').onchange = function() {
    if ( document.getElementById('icd').checked === false ) {
        planhide();
    }
};​
```

Answer (score 3):

Include onchange option in the input tag and then add an intermediate function that checks and calls planhide() accordingly as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="icd" name="icd" value="icd" onchange=check()/>
```

Then define the check() to do check the state and call the function as follows:

```
function check()
{
if(document.getElementById("icd").checked==false)
planhide();
}
```

Also instead of onchange you can also use onclick on the submit button option to call the check() function as like follows:

```
<input type="button" onclick=check()/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#icd').change(function () {
      if (!this.checked) {
          planhide();
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: You should add some form of explanation, try and avoid code only answers as they are of limited use to the OP and future visitors

Answer (score 0):

just register an `onchange` handler on your input, check the 'checked' property when the handler is call, and call the method if checked is false.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw96C/)